# Dynamic index in ng-repeat value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple ng-repeat iterating through an array of objects.

The ng-repeat contains a ng-model input element for which I need to use a dynamic value as the array index. Probably very unclear explanation so here is the code :

```
<div ng-repeat="property in current_data.object_subtype.object_property_type" ng-init="set_input_state()" class="input-group ng-scope disabled">
  <span class="input-group-addon">{{property.name}}</span>
  <input type="text" placeholder="{{property.name}}" ng-model="current_data.properties[getIndexFromId(current_data.properties, property.object_property_type_id)].value" class="form-control" disabled="disabled">
```

The problem is that the input stays empty. I've tested some combinations and found this to work :

1. `getIndexFromId(current_data.properties, property.object_property_type_id) == 0`
2. `current_data.properties[0].value` gives the expected output

So somehow `getIndexFromId(current_data.properties, property.object_property_type_id)`is not well accepted by Angular or I made a stupid mistake somewhere ...

Does anyone know what's wrong with this?

Thanks!

[edit]

Here is a sample of the data behind all this :

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Robert Smith",
  "object_subtype_id": 1,
  "object_subtype": {
    "id": 1,
    "description": "Manager",
    "object_property_type": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "description": "Phone number"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "description": "Hair color"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "description": "Nickname"
      }
    ]
  },
  "properties": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "value": "819-583-4855",
      "object_property_type_id": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "value": "Mauves",
      "object_property_type_id": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "value": "Bob",
      "object_property_type_id": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you have a pre-determined index set for each key? If not, you could try using `$index` instead.

Comment: Yes, the index is stored in the database. For now it is 1, 2, 3 etc. but it won't always be the case

Comment: can you show us the data model?

Comment: I added the JSON source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've seen of Angular, the content of the attributes are not executed as javascript. It's a [custom parsed and executed mini-language](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/parse.js) that doesn't support complex indexing.

With that said, its probably for the best. Any sufficiently complex logic should be handled by the controller or a service.

```
function MyController($scope) {
    $scope.set_current_data_value = function (current_data, property) {
        var index = $scope.getIndexFromId(current_data.properties, property.object_property_type_id);

        current_data.properties[index].value = $scope.property_name;
    }
}
```

Then your html would look something like:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="{{property.name}}" ng-model="property_name" ng-change="set_current_data_value(current_data, property)" class="form-control" disabled="disabled">
```

You may also be able to use `ng-submit` if you don't need to update your model in real time.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, I tought it was parsed as Javascript, i Guess I was wrong on this! Handling more complex logic in the controller also makes more sense, and it works great. Thank you!